# Привязка учётной записи к номеру телефона

Tags: предложение, настройки-профиля

В следствии того, что создание липовых/однодневных/одновопросных учётных записей не составляет большого труда, насколько велика вероятность того, что когда-нибудь профиль SO нужно будет привязать к номеру телефона? На мой взгляд, использование SIM-карты для идентификации пользователя более надёжней, чем существующие механизмы.
Помимо этого, это помогло бы избежать лавин некачественных вопросов.

Вопрос: рассматривалась ли это ранее?
Если "да", то по каким причинам не было сделано?
Если "нет", то по каким причинам нельзя это рассмотреть сейчас?

Comment: Каким образом привязка к телефону может помешать некачественным вопросам?

Comment: @Grundy SIM карту сложнее поменять, если номер заблокирован, чем ещё один аккаунт создать, или? Т.е. те кто, сейчас для отдельных вопросов создают отдельные аккаунты, уже не смогут так сделать. Ну по крайней мере это будет не так легко, как сейчас.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Не думаю, что требование привязки учётной записи к номеру телефона что-то улучшит в плане публикации вопросов низкого качества. Ваше предположение строится на том факте, что мусорные вопросы в основном объёме создаются одними и теми же людьми, которые регистрируют новые аккаунты каждый раз, когда на прежний аккаунт накладываются [ограничения в плане публикации вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). Я очень сомневаюсь, что это действительно так. Более того, у модераторов уже есть инструменты, позволяющие с определённой долей вероятности выявлять клонов учётных записей и объединять их в одну.

При этом стоит понимать, что требование хранения номера потребует от Stack Exchange реализовать возможности по отправке подтверждающих SMS или делать звонки. Это довольно серьёзная доработка.

А ещё здесь может сыграть закон о требовании хранить персональные данные граждан РФ на серверах на территории РФ. Насколько я понимаю, номер телефона как раз относится к таким данным.

Ну и напоследок, оформить новую сим-карту не так уж и сложно, если человек действительно захочет даже при всех этих ограничениях "завалить" SE низкокачественными вопросами.

Comment: Но обсудить этот вопрос можно-же, или уже обсуждали?

Comment: @XelaNimed мой ответ не подходит под формат "обсуждения"?

Comment: @XelaNimed, ну так вроде бы и обсуждаем сейчас.

Comment: @XelaNimed, я целиком и полностью поддерживаю точку зрения αλεχολυτ. Для фильтрации низкокачественных вопросов есть очереди проверки, голоса, тревоги, инструменты модерации, боты. Задача сообщества ознакомить новых участников с правилами сервиса и поделиться знаниями. Я видел множество аккаунтов, которые начинались с низкокачественных вопросов. Но потом люди ознакомились с сервисом, стали сами отвечать на вопросы, проверять очереди и в итоге превратились в постоянных участников, создающих качественный контент...Все с чего то начинали.

Comment: С доводами о сохранении персональных данных согласен. Не понимаю, почему сам об этом не подумал.

Answer (score 7):

Не нашел похожего обсуждения ни здесь, ни на метамете, но вижу как минимум две причины по которым ввод обязательного номера телефона маловероятен.

### Stack Exchange разрешает создавать несколько учетных записей

Stack Exchange разрешает пользователю регистрироваться несколько раз, если пользователь не использует это для нарушения правил (избегания блокировок, накрутки репутации. Это обсуждалось на главной мете: [Why are people allowed to have multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72277/why-are-people-allowed-to-have-multiple-user-accounts)

Кроме простого аргумента: «если человек не нарушает правила, то не нужно его трогать» в обсуждении привели примеры сценариев, в которых человеку может понадобится несколько учетных записей:

- Новички забывают про свои учетки и создают их заново. Если при этом они не упираются в ограничения сайта, то это считается нормальным.
- Люди задают вопросы анонимно: либо хотят посмотреть на сайт со стороны, либо не хотят портить себе репутацию.

Полагаю, что у сайта есть механизмы, которые позволяют отлавливать тех, кто злоупотребляет правилами. Возможно, они не всегда эффективны, но лично я не замечал у нас явной «атаки клонов».

### Пользователи дорожат приватностью

Совсем недавно на Meta.SO [поднялась волна возмущения](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379804/please-dont-share-my-e-mail-with-amazon-without-my-express-consent/) когда сайт слил часть email-адресов Amazon для рассылки подарков. Полагаю, что любое требование вводить свой номер телефона будет воспринято сообществом в штыки, тем более если его сделают обязательным.

Кроме того, сайт в прошлом году приводил функции в соответствие с [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation). Я не специалист по праву и могу ошибаться, но насколько я понимаю регламент позволяет пользователю в любой момент запросить удаление своих личных данных, в том числе и номера телефона. Возможность такого удаления делает блокировку по номеру телефона бессмысленной.

Comment: Возможность удаления личных данных, имхо, предполагает и возможность одновременного удаления аккаунта. Так что по поводу GDPR не очень понимаю проблему.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Как я понимаю: человек регистрируется с номером, просит удалить учетку и на следующий день снова регистрируется с тем же номером. Не силен в этом вопросе, поэтому могу сильно заблуждаться.

Comment: Теперь понял. Да, такой сценарий вполне себе был бы возможен. Но, мне кажется, можно и сейчас удалить аккаунт и после этого создать новый с тем же самым Email. Сняв при этом ограничения, которые висели на удаляемом аккаунте. Но вообще надо уточнить.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Да, можно. Я это к тому, что хранение телефона не поможет SO отслеживать пользователя, т.к. SO обязан удалять номер при удалении учетки. Отслеживать нарушителей по IP закон вроде как не запрещает.

Answer (score 3):

Надоело уже, что все зачем-то хотят телефон. Очень надеюсь, что такого никогда не будет хотя бы здесь.

Comment: Не знаю как все, но я хотел бы меньшее количество пользователей, которые никаким образом не заинтересованы в создании качественного вопроса... Начиная от банальной орфографии и заканчивая декларативными указаниями о том, что и как им должны сделать. Исходя из этого и спрашиваю о причинах, по которым это не было до сих пор реализовано.

Comment: Или просто кто-то боится деанонизации...

Comment: Действительно, ведь это неэффективно. Человек может приобрести несколько номеров. Для того чтобы система работала нужна обязательная сверка с государственной системой идентификации.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, у Николаса есть мои адрес и телефон. Он же мне подарки отправлял. UPDATE: Кажется, я неправильно понял твой комментарий.

Comment: @defaultlocale и отпечатки пусть сдаст при регистрации!